# Get part of url from Laravel named route

Tags: laravel, routes

Is there a possibility to get the part of url, that is defined in route?
For example with this route:

```
Route::get('/editor/{id}', 'EditorController@editor')->name('editorNew');
```

after using mentioned functionality, let's say `route_link();` i would like to get:

```
$route_link = route_link('editorNew', array('id' => 1));
//$route_link containts "/editor/1"
```

I tried to use `route()`, but i got `http://localhost/app/public/editor-new/1` instead of `/editor-new/1` and that's not what i wanted.
For clarity need this functionality to generate links depending on machine, that the app is fired on (integration with Shopify).

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route?

Comment: What do you want, you want http://mydomain.tld/editor/1?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `route` method to get the relative path by passing `false` in the third parameter as:

```
route('editorNew', [1], false); // returns '/editor-new/1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
$route_link = route('editorNew', [1]);
```

`1` is the first value that will be on the route, at this moment `{id}`.

If you want to use the paramater (`id`) in your method, it will be the following:

```
public function editor($id) {
    //your code
}
```

And in the view you could use:

```
Route::input('id');
```

Hope this works!