# How do I get route() function in Blade template to return just '/some/path' instead of 'http://blahblah.com/some/path'?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My template code looks like this:

```
{{ route('about') }}
```

It seems like I'm missing part of the equation.

The problem popped up after an update—and now I am have all sorts of 'mixed content' security problems, because some paths are `http://` and some are `https://`.

Comment: "*The problem popped up after an update*" - you didn't mention or tag the Laravel versions ... ?  In any case, searching for "*laravel route relative*" turns up the standard answer: `route('about', [], false)` - which has worked since v4 (https://stackoverflow.com/q/35490601/6089612, 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/52589851/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41263991/6089612, ...)  A bit more searching shows the described parameter [still exists in Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_route). 
 Maybe your `APP_URL` or related changed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get relative URLs with url() in Laravel 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490601/how-to-get-relative-urls-with-url-in-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 0):

The `route` function returns the absolute URL in default.

If you need to get the relative link, you need to pass the third parameter as `false`:

```php
{{ route('about', [], false) }}
```